# How to replace a leading zero with white space in SED?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

Trying to find how to replace a leading zero with white space in SED. Attempting to get day of month and replace with space to filter some data that I am screen scraping.

The code I have is as follows:

```
DoM=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%d")
DoMSp=$(echo $DoM | sed "s/^0*/\ /g"); echo $DoMSp
```

But the problem is when I have a day from 1-9 instead of printing " 1" it prints "1", no matter how many "\ " I try to put in the expression.

```
$ DoMSp=$(echo $DoM | sed "s/^0*/\ /g"); echo $DoMSp
1

$ DoMSp=$(echo $DoM | sed "s/^0*/\ \ \ \ \ \ /g"); echo $DoMSp
1
```

Comment: Quote your expansion on the echo, otherwise it strips whitespace.

Comment: This might just be your example, but what about using `date --date "-1 day" +"%_d"` or `date --date "-1 day" +"%e"`. Those make `date` return a space-padded field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to escape space in `sed` command, just use double quote in `echo` command to avoid [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting):

```
$ DoMSp=$(echo "$DoM" | sed "s/^0*/ /"); echo "$DoMSp"
 1
```

Comment: @GautamSomani: The pattern only match at start of line, so it's not a problem. But it is still not necessary to use `g` here, removed it!

Comment: Yup. Agreed. Will delete my comment.